# @Column name ignored JPA

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, datanucleus

Using Google App Engine in conjunction with MySQL

JPA is ignoring my column alias

I've tried declaring on variable:

```
@Column(name = "fk_location_id") 
private Long locationId;
```

I've also tried declaring on getter:

```
@Column(name = "fk_location_id") 
public Long getLocationId() {
    return locationId;
}
```

I've also tried declaring on both

None work. Just throwing error:

```
Caused by: org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.exceptions.MissingColumnException: Required columns missing from table fk_location_id
```

I've googled around and found stuff related to Hibernate but don't believe I'm using that?

Here is my persistence.xml file

```
<property name="datanucleus.ConnectionDriverName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc://mydb..." />
<property name="datanucleus.ConnectionUserName" value="user" />
<property name="datanucleus.ConnectionPassword" value="pass" />
<property name="datanucleus.autoStartMechanism" value="None" />
<property name="datanucleus.validateTables" value="true" />
<property name="datanucleus.validateConstraints" value="true" />
<property name="datanucleus.validateColumns" value="true" />
<property name="datanucleus.DetachAllOnCommit" value="true" />
<property name="datanucleus.maxFetchDepth" value="1" />
<property name="datanucleus.storeManagerType" value="rdbms" />
```

Here is the schema for table:

```
CREATE TABLE `sites` (
`id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
`fk_location_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

How I query the DB:

```
EntityManagerFactory factory;
factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Globals.PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

Query q = em.createQuery("select t from Site t");
List<Site> siteList = q.getResultList();
```

Java Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sites")
public class Site {

private Long id;
private String name;
private Long locationId;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public Long getLocationId() {
    return locationId;
}

public void setLocationId(Long locationId) {
    this.locationId = locationId;
}

}
```

The error tell FKLOCATIONID column not found so its searching for FKLOCATIONID when it should be searching for fk_location_id

Comment: @NeilStockton Ok I have updated by persistence file. I have both jdoconfig and persistence because thats what the project template ships with? Not sure if its harmful. However even after removing redundant code from persistence file,  the column mapping problem still exists, any clue what to do? I'm also not sure what eclipse link does so I took that out too. What I'm left with still gets my data, just column alias not working

Comment: Ok no problem, was unaware. Also your reputation amount gives you ability to edit other people's questions and remove tags

Comment: Then when you've done that, post the versions of the software you're using, Post the code you're using to generate the database (DataNucleus SchemaTool?, JPA 2.1 Schema Generation?, generate on the fly). Then post the DDL that is generated to generate the schema (in the log).

Comment: I created my database through a series of SQL statements (create table, etc). Then I'm using this to connect to my already created database and map data into objects. So not sure if I'm using any tool? Don't see any logs. I updated my question to show how I query the DB.

Comment: If you're generating the DB through some other means then tell us what is the schema for this Entity (and if you generate the schema through some other means then why do you have persistence properties to generate the schema???). And if you submit a query then tell us what SQL is issued for this query

Comment: The mystery is unfolding but still have problem. I removed auto generate schema, it was actually adding LOCATIONID as an extra column instead of mapping to fk_location_id. But now that I remove schema generation, I get an error that LOCATIONID column does not exist in table (which it doesn't because it should map to fk_location_id). Do you understand the problem and what I'm asking?

Comment: so provide FULL information please. Post the FULL entity and whatever metadata defines it.

Comment: Do I need a custom naming identifier in my persistence file? something like <property name="datanucleus.identifierFactory" value="myCustom..." />?

Comment: I posted the Java class and error log underneath it

Comment: Nowhere is "FKLOCATIONID" specified (and the error you post has underscores present so no idea what you refer to now) ... and there is no @Column in your class posted, so it won't just invent that name. Consequently you aren't showing consistent info

Comment: While you're at it, define the package of @Column annotation being used (which it isn't in your posted class)

Comment: Finally if you put annotations on getters then you have to be consistent and not put others on fields! And again, quote the VERSIONS of the software being used. Barring that, go to the website of the software you use and use their forum ... this is not a suitable medium for such imprecise questions

Comment: Well this is embarrassing... I was using the javax.jdo.annotations.Column instead of javax.persistence.Column and as soon as I switched problem solved. Thanks for toughing it out with me! Please make this an answer so I can accept and upvote :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the `@Column` annotation is from `javax.persistence` and not from JDO or somewhere else. DataNucleus can only use either JDO or JPA annotations but not a mix of both